# Styling numbers of outside ordered list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

Is it possible to format the numbers of an ordered list with the list-position-style set to outside? I'd like to do this using only css if possible, since I can't edit the html. Basically, I'd like the styled numbers with the round background to take the place of the outside numbers. Thanks everyone!

```css
 ol {
   list-position-style: outside;
   counter-reset: item;
 }
 li {
   counter-increment: item;
   margin-bottom: 5px;

 }
 li:before {
   margin-right: 10px;
   content: counter(item);
   background: lightblue;
   border-radius: 100%;
   color: white;
   width: 1.2em;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

```html
<ol>
   <li><span>blah blah blah.</span>
   <ol type="a" class="ol substeps">
   <li>blah blah</li>
     <li>blah</li>
     </ol>
</li>
  <li>blah blah blah blah</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, it's not `list-position-style` it's `list-style-position`. Anyway, just `list-style: none;` it so that to hide the numbers, then apply `position: relative;` to `li` and `position: absolute;` to its `:before`. Just take a look on what I have done below:

```css
ol {
   list-style: none;
   counter-reset: item;
 }
 li {
   counter-increment: item;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
 }
 li:before {
   margin-right: 10px;
   content: counter(item);
   background: lightblue;
   border-radius: 100%;
   color: white;
   width: 1.2em;
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   left: -25px;
 }
```

```html
<ol>
   <li><span>blah blah blah.</span>
   <ol type="a" class="ol substeps">
   <li>blah blah</li>
     <li>blah</li>
     </ol>
</li>
  <li>blah blah blah blah</li>
</ol>
```